# How to make Frame/Panel fit label of text with fixed width but variable height

Tags: java, swing

I have a label with an unknown amount of text. I need to display this label in a panel. The panel must have a fixed width, but the height needs to be changed to adjust to perfectly wrap whatever the text turns out to be.

So, suppose I have a limit on width of 400 pixels. The text it has to display turns out be 80 words. I need to make this text wrap onto new lines, so its basically a paragraph that is 400 pixels wide, and a previously unknown height. The height of the container needs to be no bigger than is necessary to display the paragraph.

I would love to be able to do this with some sort of layout manager that will work when I resize the frame, so if the width limit changes to say 500 pixels, the height of the label containing the existing paragraph will resize so that there is never more height that is necessary to display the label.

Think of it like someone posting an answer to this question on Stack Overflow. The width of your response is limited to the width of the div in the HTML of this site, but it's going to adjust the height of your div so that it fits your entire answer, no more and no less. I feel like I'm going crazy here; this seems like such basic functionality there has to be a simple way of doing it in Java Swing.

Here is an example of what I'm talking about. Here is a long sentence in a single line without any width restriction.

[image]

However, that's too wide because there's a 400 pixel width restriction. It needs to look like this:

[image]

Is there a way I can accomplish this wrapping + fitting height to contents with a layout manager, hopefully a box manager? Could you please give an example of the code? It needs to give the correct height for the label based on the amount of text, and I'd really like it to work when the frame gets resized as well.

Here is what I have. It doesn't work because it specifies the height based on the example text, but I need to be able to deal with a variable amount of text, so I can plug in any paragraph and the height of the label will be correct.

```java
public class Playground {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();      
        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        myFrame.setBackground(Color.red);
                
        myFrame.setSize(new Dimension(400, 600));       
        
        JPanel groupPanel = new JPanel();
        myFrame.add(groupPanel);
        
        groupPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(groupPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        groupPanel.setBackground(Color.green);  

        JPanel itemPanel = new JPanel();
        groupPanel.add(itemPanel);
        
        itemPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
        
        String msg = "<html><p>This is going to be a really long message that says a lot of words but doesnt really say anything. ";
        msg += "We want label containing the message (and the itemPanel that contains it) to always have as much height as necessary ";
        msg += "to display the message given the width of the frame</p></html>";
        
        JLabel testLabel = new JLabel(msg);
        testLabel.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        testLabel.setOpaque(true);
        
        itemPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 64));
        itemPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 64));
        itemPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(400, 64));
        
        itemPanel.add(testLabel);
        
        myFrame.pack();
        myFrame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

This was a previous answer that helped by getting the frame to pack around a 400px paragraph:

> If the only reason you need HTML is for wrapping, then maybe you can
> use a JTextArea instead:
>
> ```
> //JLabel testLabel = new JLabel(msg);
> JTextArea testLabel = new JTextArea();
> testLabel.setText(msg);
> testLabel.setLineWrap( true );
> testLabel.setWrapStyleWord( true );
> testLabel.setSize(400, 1);
> ```
>
> The setSize(...) statement will provide the hint for the text area on
> when to wrap so it can calculate its actual preferred size.
>
> You can always set the properties of the text area to make is look
> like a label.

It helps when the frame is initialized, but when I resize the frame the height of the label doesn't change, so maybe I just have to keep calling pack? I'm not sure how I would place that in an event handler though.

Comment: Well you didn't really appreciate the help you got in your last question on this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68490688/131872. I specifically stated the answer was for a JTextArea not a JLabel because you question only stated you "used HTML for the wrapping", so I suggested an alternative. When I implemented the suggestion the text was displayed on 4 lines on a packed frame with a width of 400, which is what I understand you are attempting to do.. Why would you delete the previous question? Everybody should see what has been suggested so people don't make the same suggestion.

Comment: I deleted the previous question because every attempt I did to replicate your solution did not work. I got something that was 4 lines but the frame was not packed. Probably because you posted 4 lines of code simply commenting out my label and replacing it with 4 lines, which I did but had no effect. The answer didnt work and when I replied why the answer didnt work it seemed better to post a clearer question. I appreciate your help but if you would be kind enough to post the complete code in your answer maybe I could make it work

Comment: Wow my mistake I don't know why it wasnt packed before but now that I'm trying it again it is packed. I'm not sure what's different. Sorry about that. The question remains though that when I resize the frame The width of the TextArea adjusts but the height does not. Can this be handled with a layout manager or do I have to actually write some handler for when the frame gets resized? If I did that, what would the handler look like? Thanks again

Comment: Well I can't answer because the question was deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Back to the JLabel and HTML:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Playground {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();
        myFrame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        myFrame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 130));
        JPanel groupPanel = new JPanel();
        groupPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
        String msg = "<html><p align='justify'>This is going to be a really long "
                + "message that says a lot of words but doesnt really say anything. "
                + "We want label containing the message (and the itemPanel that "
                + "contains it to always have as much height as necessary to display "
                + "the message given the width of the frame.</p></html>";
        JLabel testLabel = new JLabel(msg);
        testLabel.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        testLabel.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
        testLabel.setOpaque(true);
        groupPanel.add(testLabel);
        myFrame.add(groupPanel);
        myFrame.pack();
        myFrame.setVisible(true);
        myFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        
    }
}
```

And here is what the code does:

[image]